# Should I add (check in) my project management system backup to repository?

Tags: svn, backup, repository, trac, redmine

I installed and set up Redmine project management application. Now I need to setup its backups (which include database dump + "files" directory). But I have a question:
Do I have to check in my Redmine backups into my SVN repository or not?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to put backup files in subversion. Subversion is designed as a version control system, backups don't need to be version controlled.

Instead include the redmine backups in your normal backup schedule, and also make sure the Subversion repository is backed up.